# Resetting Win CE Registry

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I was working on a win CE 5.0 device and changed the registry value of Launch50 (which is normally explorer.exe) to point to my application. The Problem is that the path specified in the registry entry is wrong and the device does not boot up properly. I do not have a means of connecting this device to my PC. is there a way to fix the registry entry by booting into a SD card or something of that sort. If there is How do I do this? The Device is a mini Point of sale (Wintec IDT700)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tough.  Reverting to the factory state is very device specific. First stop is to check with the OEM.

Does the device have a mechanism to auto-run an app at startup from an inserted media or similar?  If y\so, creating an app to modify the registry back would be an alternative.